# Determine status of state of Kubernetes port forwarding

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to find a way to determine the status of the "kubectl port-forward" command.
There is a way to determine the readiness of a pod, a node...: i.e. "kubectl get pods" etc...

Is there a way to determine if the kubectl port-forward command has completed and ready to work?

Thank you.

Comment: IME `kubectl port-forward` is slow and unreliable; it's a super-handy debugging tool, but if you're starting to look at scripting it, you might be better off setting up a proper ingress path into your cluster.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same understanding as you @VKR.

The way that I choose to solve this was to have a loop with a curl every second to check the status of the forwarded port. It works but I had hoped for a prebaked solution to this.

```
do curl:6379
timer=0
while curl is false and timer <100
  timer++
  curl:6379
  sleep 1
```

Thank you @Nicola and @David, I will keep those in mind when I get past development testing.

Answer (score 1):

Answering directly to your question - no, you can not determine the status of `kubectl port-forward` command. 
The only way of  determining what is going on in the background is to inspect the output of this command.
The output will be something like:

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:6379 -> 6379
Forwarding from [::1]:6379 -> 6379
```

I may suggest using [service type NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport)  instead of `port-forward`.
Using the `NodePort`, you are able to expose your app as a service and have access from outside the Kubernetes.
For more examples [use this url](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/).